# Switch Statement Based On String?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have a string of instructions that feed in via a textfield, I want to take the latest value and perform an action based on its value.

The question is, why doesnt this code work? 'instruction' prints the string value i want to use correctly corresponding to the statement, but i always get the "wasnt a recognised character" default case...

```
    func processInputCommand() {
    print("processing called")
    let string = self.robotInstructions.text!
    let commands = Array(string.characters)
    let instruction = String(describing: commands.last)
    print(instruction)

        switch instruction {
        case "N" :
            self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition + 1
        case "S" :
            self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition - 1
        case "E" :
            self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition + 1
        case "W" :
            self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition - 1
        case "P" :
            pickUpGummyBears()
        case "D" :
            if self.usersRobot.numberOfBagsHeld > 0 {
                dropGummyBears()
            } else {
                print("THE ROBOT ISNT HOLDING ANY BAGS CURRENTLY")
            }
        default:
            print("WASNT RECOGNISED CHARACTER")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the safe way by `guard`ing `string` and `instruction`:

```
func processInputCommand() {
    print("processing called")

    guard let string = self.robotInstructions.text, 
        let instruction = string.characters.last else { 
            print("INVALID INPUT")
            return 
        }

    switch instruction {
    case "N" :
        self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition + 1
    case "S" :
        self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition - 1
    case "E" :
        self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition + 1
    case "W" :
        self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition - 1
    case "P" :
        pickUpGummyBears()
    case "D" :
        if self.usersRobot.numberOfBagsHeld > 0 {
            dropGummyBears()
        } else {
            print("THE ROBOT ISNT HOLDING ANY BAGS CURRENTLY")
        }
    default:
        print("WASNT RECOGNISED CHARACTER")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `command.last` in the line below returns an optional. You need to unwrap the value:

```
let instruction = String(describing: commands.last)
```

Modify your code like this:

```
let commands = Array(string.characters)
//unwrap the value here
guard let last = commands.last else {return}
let instruction = String(describing: last)
print(instruction)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Hussain Shabbir's answer, the type of `commands.last` is `Optional<Character>` (aka `Character?`). An example of using it directly in `switch`-statement.

```
func processInputCommand() {
    print("processing called")
    let string = self.robotInstructions.text!
    let commands = string.characters
    let instruction = commands.last
    print(instruction) //->causes warning, please ignore

    switch instruction {
    //`"N"?` is a shortcut form of `Optional.Some("N")`
    //And `"N"` is taken as a Character
    case "N"?:
        self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition + 1
    case "S"?:
        self.usersRobot.yPosition = self.usersRobot.yPosition - 1
    case "E"?:
        self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition + 1
    case "W"?:
        self.usersRobot.xPosition = self.usersRobot.xPosition - 1
    case "P"?:
        pickUpGummyBears()
    case "D"?:
        if self.usersRobot.numberOfBagsHeld > 0 {
            dropGummyBears()
        } else {
            print("THE ROBOT ISNT HOLDING ANY BAGS CURRENTLY")
        }
    case nil:
        print("commands is emptry")
    default:
        print("WASNT RECOGNISED CHARACTER")
    }
}
```